# Get selection geometry from select interaction

Tags: openlayers

I have a select interaction that is drawn in the map as a polygon while the map features was not loaded because of scale limit on the layer.

When I zoom in so that the features load, I want to apply a selection style on the newly loaded features that is inside the selection polygon.

I have a custom loader on the data layer, so I can get the selection interaction during the load. The problem is that I can't find any api to get the polygon geometry from the selection interaction. I do have the interaction object available.

How can I solve this?

Comment: How do you code to trigger selection?

Answer (score 0):

You can **get the features** from an OpenLayers **select interaction** using the [getFeatures method](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.interaction.Select.html#getFeatures).  From there you can get the feature geometry.  Here's an example:

```
var features = selectInteraction.getFeatures();
var polyFeature = features.item(0); // we suppose your feature is the first one
// from there, do what you want with your feature, i.e. get its geometry:
var geometry = polyFeature.getGeometry();
// or set a style
var style = new ol.style.Style({
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6)'
    })
);
polyFeature.setStyle(style);
```

Comment: The problem is that getFeatures is empty, because the features were not loaded in the map at the time the selection polygon was drawn. What I need to do is "re-run" the selection after the features has been loaded. If I can get hold of the polygon that defines the lasso of the selection, I can do this when the features load.